# CSS Layout Approach: Rounded Corner not CSS3 & images along sides (not just corners)

Tags: html, css, layout

- I need to make CSS layout that has a minimum-width and minimum-height but will expand to 80% of the browser size.
- The main div will have rounded corners (using images because no support for CSS3) - however, there is also images that run between the corners on the top and bottom and on the left and right sides.  This also provides a drop shadow effect.
- The challenge is that because I have the div which position:relative and my corners are then position: absolute (all is good at this point), but then I want my middle images to expand to fill the space between the corners.  Except that this doesn't work properly, it extends past the end of the div.
- I am open to a brand new approach, I'm including images and code below, but feel free to solve with code uses background colors vs having to use my images.

Here is what I am trying to achieve:

[image: wireframe]
Here are the images for the container:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCgFR.jpg

Here is some code ...

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="pageWrapper">
        <div class="contentWrapper">
            <span class="top-left"></span>
            <span class="top-middle"></span>
            <span class="top-right"></span>
            <span class="bottom-left"></span>
            <span class="bottom-middle"></span>
            <span class="bottom-right"></span>
            <div class="content">
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dotor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
                    Ut viverra lectus vitae est ullamcorper a tempus est commodo. 
                    Phasellus et pulvinar risus. Cras quis aliquet odio. Ut condimentum porta mi ultrices elementum. 
                    Maecenas feugiat magna at tellus convallis congue. Aenean tincidunt rutrum varius. Aenean nec eros id odio dapibus faucibus. 
                    Pellentesque blandit gravida erat id sodales. Etiam nunc odio, pharetra nec aliquam a, gravida at metus. Nullam dapibus vulputate blandit. 
                    Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Vestibulum ullamcorper lectus ut sapien scelerisque 
                    vitae ullamcorper mauris venenatis.
                </p>
            </div>  
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body {
background-color: #eeeee7;
}

.pageWrapper {
margin: 0px auto;       /* centers the div horizontally */
min-width: 900px;
min-height: 430px;
height: 80%;
width: 80%;
background-color: red;
}

.contentWrapper {
position: relative;        /* makes our corners absolute relative to our container not our browser window    */
background-color: yellow;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
padding-right: 34px;
padding-left: 34px;
padding-top: 155px;
}

.top-left,
.top-right {
position: absolute;
height: 155px;
width: 34px;
background-color: blue;
}

.bottom-left,
.bottom-right {
position: absolute;
height: 29px;
width: 34px;
}

.top-left {
top: 0;
left: 0;
background-image:url('images/cornerLeftTop.jpg');
 }
 .top-right {
top: 0;
right: 0;
background-image:url('images/cornerRightTop.jpg');
 }
.bottom-left {
bottom: 0; 
left: 0;
background-image:url('images/cornerBottomLeft.jpg');
 }
.bottom-right {
bottom: 0;
right: 0;
background-image:url('images/cornerBottomRight.jpg');
 }
 .top-middle {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 34px;
height: 155px;
width: 100%;
background-image:url('images/headerMiddle.jpg');
}

.bottom-middle {
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
height: 29px;
width: 100%;
background-image:url('images/footerMiddle.jpg');
}

.middle-left {

}

.middle-right {
```

}

Comment: My question is "Why is there no support for CSS3?" This method is so antiquated. I'd recommend either:
A: Use CSS3, and degrade to square corners in < IE9
B: Use square corners

If the system is stuck in <IE9, how important are rounded corners, really?

Comment: I need to support old browsers ... not my requirement, that of my workplace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me, I'm still perfecting the min-width which doesn't work in < ie 8.  I realize there are modern ways to do this.  But, I work for a place that must still support some ie 6 users.  This works!

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="pageWrapper">
        <div class="contentWrapper">    
            <div class="headerMiddle">
            </div>
            <span class="top-left"></span>
            <span class="top-right"></span>
            <div class="contentRight">
            </div>                                  
            <div class="contentLeft">
            </div>  
            <div class="content">                   
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dotor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
                    Ut viverra lectus vitae est ullamcorper a tempus est commodo. 
                    Phasellus et pulvinar risus. Cras quis aliquet odio. Ut condimentum porta mi ultrices elementum. 
                    Maecenas feugiat magna at tellus convallis congue. Aenean tincidunt rutrum varius. Aenean nec eros id odio dapibus faucibus. 
                    Pellentesque blandit gravida erat id sodales. Etiam nunc odio, pharetra nec aliquam a, gravida at metus. Nullam dapibus vulputate blandit. 
                    Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Vestibulum ullamcorper lectus ut sapien scelerisque 
                    vitae ullamcorper mauris venenatis.
                </p>
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dotor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
                    Ut viverra lectus vitae est ullamcorper a tempus est commodo. 
                    Phasellus et pulvinar risus. Cras quis aliquet odio. Ut condimentum porta mi ultrices elementum. 
                    Maecenas feugiat magna at tellus convallis congue. Aenean tincidunt rutrum varius. Aenean nec eros id odio dapibus faucibus. 
                    Pellentesque blandit gravida erat id sodales. Etiam nunc odio, pharetra nec aliquam a, gravida at metus. Nullam dapibus vulputate blandit. 
                    Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Vestibulum ullamcorper lectus ut sapien scelerisque 
                    vitae ullamcorper mauris venenatis.
                </p>                    
            </div>

            <div class="footerMiddle">
            </div>
            <span class="bottom-left"></span>
            <span class="bottom-right"></span>      
        </div>  
    </div>
</body>
```

```
body {
    background-color: #eeeee7;
    text-align:center;
}

.pageWrapper {
    margin: 0px auto;       /* centers the div horizontally */
    min-width: 900px;
    height: 768px;
    width: 80%;
}

.contentWrapper {
    position: relative;        /* makes our corners absolute relative to our container not our browser window    */
    background-color: white;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 155px;
    text-align: left;
}

.content {
    padding: 75px;
}

.headerMiddle {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 155px;
    width: 100%;
    background-image:url('images/headerMiddle.jpg');
}

.footerMiddle {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 29px;
    width: 100%;
    background-image:url('images/footerMiddle.jpg');    
}

.contentLeft {
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    width: 34px;
    background-image:url('images/contentLeft.jpg');
}

.contentRight {
    float: right;
    height: 100%;
    width: 34px;
    background-image:url('images/contentRight.jpg');
}

.top-left,
.top-right {
    position: absolute;
    height: 155px;
    width: 34px;
    background-color: blue;
}

.top-left {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-image:url('images/cornerLeftTop.jpg');
}

.top-right {
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-image:url('images/cornerRightTop.jpg');
}

.bottom-left,
.bottom-right {
    position: absolute;
    height: 29px;
    width: 34px;
}

.bottom-left {
    bottom: 0; 
    left: 0;
    background-image:url('images/cornerBottomLeft.jpg');
}
.bottom-right {
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-image:url('images/cornerBottomRight.jpg');
}

.minWidth {
    width: 600px;
    height:1px;
}
```

Comment: I solved the ie issue by adding a doctype <!DOCTYPE html>, so ie. didn't go into quirks mode.